# Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, id) - Not found error

Tags: api, google-apps-script, gmail

Has anyone else found that the Advanced Gmail Service call

```
`Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, id)`
```

is now giving errors? Does anyone have a fix?

I had a reliable script that deleted Spam and Trash every few hours. Since about 21 Feb 17 it is giving the error "Not Found" even when passed a valid thread ID.

This is the script. I've added some logging messages

```
function deleteForever() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getSpamThreads(0, 100);
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  for (var i = threads.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
     var thisid=threads[i].getId();
        Logger.log("Removing thread " +i + ' of ' + threads.length + " from Spam with ID = " + thisid);

    try {
    var thisthread=GmailApp.getThreadById(thisid);
    Logger.log("Found the thread.");
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, thisid);
    }catch(err) {
     Logger.log("Error " + err.message);
    };

  }
  Logger.log("Finished removing " + threads.length + " threads from Spam.");

  var threads = GmailApp.getTrashThreads(0, 100);
  for (var i = threads.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
        Logger.log("Removing thread " +i + ' of ' + threads.length + " from Trash");
    try {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, threads[i].getId());
    } catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error " + err.message);
    };
  }
  Logger.log("Finished removing " + threads.length + " threads from Trash.");
}
```

Now it is just giving a Not Found Error.

```
[17-02-25 11:45:49:790 GMT] Removing thread 17 of 18 from Spam with ID = 15a6fe6c1a86a020
[17-02-25 11:45:49:829 GMT] Found the thread.
[17-02-25 11:45:49:959 GMT] Error Not Found
[17-02-25 11:45:49:959 GMT] Removing thread 16 of 18 from Spam with ID = 15a6fe6c168f4a03
[17-02-25 11:45:50:000 GMT] Found the thread.
[17-02-25 11:45:50:129 GMT] Error Not Found
[17-02-25 11:45:50:130 GMT] Removing thread 15 of 18 from Spam with ID = 15a6fed29f6650b3
[17-02-25 11:45:50:165 GMT] Found the thread.
[17-02-25 11:45:50:294 GMT] Error Not Found
.....
    `
```

Notice that thisid is definitely set to a valid ID before attempting the remove operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are removing the message while the search function is fetching the thread.

Use

```
Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", threadId)
```

instead of

```
Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", threadId);
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Presumably where there was only 1 message in the thread, this worked, there were not many cases where the spam or trash contained a thread, but the ones that were there were not getting deleted.

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please choose the best answer and close this question.