# Permanently delete gmail via Google App

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I need  to use Google App Gmail API to permanently delete an email as the action in a gmail filter. I have enabled the Advanced Google Services gmail API and the Gmail Api in the Console. The function below deletes forever email that is in trash and labeled with 'labelname'. How can I run this function as part of a filter which is run on new email? That is, how do I execute this function as an action in a filter?

```js
function deleteForever(userId, labelName) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash label:" + labelName);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(userId, threads[i].getId());
  }
}
deleteForever('me','permdelete');
```

Comment: Can you show us line 4 of your code? Or is it already contained in the answer?

Comment: Everything is there.

Comment: Is this your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42456150/656243

Comment: I found something in stackoverflow which suggested changing: line 4 from Gmail.Users.Messages.remove to Gmail.Users.Threads.remove and that seems to make error go away and deletes the messages. Now I need to know how to call this google app script as an action in a filter or how to create a new filter that uses this function and can be triggered for all new email from a specific sender.

Comment: Thanks Lynn. Yes, that fixed the failures. Now, I need to be able to call this app from a gmail filter that is run when new mail arrives.